# Python script to deduplicate lines in multiple files

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a large number of .txt files, each of which contains a list of URLs. Within each file there are duplicate URLs. There is no duplication between files. I want to remove the deplicate URLs from within in each file.

I've written a script which worked correctly on a single file. Now I want to make it run against the large set of files.

```
path = "/users/mypath"
myfiles = os.listdir(path)
for f in myfiles:
       open(f, 'r')
       lines = f.readlines()
       seen_lines = set()
       open(f, 'w')
       for line in lines:
              if line not in seen_lines:
                   seen_lines.add(line)
                   f.write(line)
       f.close()
```

This produces the error message:

```
File "C:\Users\myscripts\myscript.py", line 66, in <module>
    lines=open(f,'r').readlines()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfile.txt'
```

I assume I have not defined the path correctly - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you should add the relative path (path to directory) when opening the file, as such

```
cur_file = open(os.path.join(path, f), 'r')
```

the same when you open the file for writing, notice that `f` is a string and won't have the `readlines`, you should `readlines` from the object returned by `open`, the same goes for writing

And by the way, if you use a `set` there is no need to check if  a line is written, as a set only allows no duplicates, you could simply add all lines to a set, and then write the set to the ouput file as such

```
output_file.write("\n".join(seen_lines))
```

and furthermore I would believe the most efficient way would be

```
for f in myfiles:
    cur_file = open(os.path.join(path, f), 'r')
    lines = set(cur_file.readlines())
    cur_file.close()
    with open(os.path.join(path, f), 'w') as of:
        of.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: You should use the `os` library to concatenate paths, never concatenate paths manually...

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I wanted it to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to concatenate the `path` to the file name in order to build the full path and assign it to a variable. Let us assume that the name of the file is stored in variable `filename`. Thus, the file can be opened using

```
f = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r')
```

You should apply the same when you open the file in `w` mode, Remember to `import os` at the beginning of your script

One additional comment on your code... You should not keep accumulating the `seen_lines` because if you have a lot of lines in your file it will need a lot of RAM memory. Instead, compute the `hash` of each line and accumulate them in a set. It will also be considerably faster than your current code.

To sum up, I would use the following code:

```
path = "/users/mypath"
myfiles = os.listdir(path)
for filename in myfiles:
       f = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r')
       lines = f.readlines()
       seen_lines = set()
       f.close()
       f = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w')
       for line in lines:
              h = hash(line)
              if h not in seen_lines:
                   seen_lines.add(h)
                   f.write(line)
       f.close()
```

Comment: This would clearly not work as you run over the file name when opening for reading, and trying to use it for writing, the rest of the code suffers from inefficiency

Comment: @rotemtal What are the inefficiencies that the code suffers from?

Comment: You are completely right. Corrected. Thanks. Can you comment on the inefficiency part? It is much more efficient than the author's code. If you have something to say for other's code, please provide arguments

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @GaneshTata. It's a pleasure to work with users like you :D

Comment: @GaneshTata the whole iteration is inefficient, but specifically the hashing is unnecessary, plus when adding to a set there is no need to check if the item exists in the set, since a set ignores duplicates, therefore, inefficient.

Comment: @rotemtal that is not true, the hashing is necessary because it reduces a lot the memory usage (from a string to an int64). The part where I check if the item is already in the set is completely necessary, not for the addition of the hash to the set but for writing the line in the file. Please when you analyse code of others think twice before commenting.

Comment: Your argument about memory is accepted, and still this is not an efficient way to perform this task, and not the correct way to use the python `set`

Comment: I don’t see your efficient proposal anywhere, @rotemtal

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
   open(f, r)
```

with

```
   f=open(os.path.join(path, f), 'r')
```

Comment: please, use `os` library to concatenate paths. Some paths will contain a `/` at the end and then your code will fail